# PHP curl not sending data

Tags: php

I tried use API, but code got error. It look like post_string isn't sending. Login to API is OK.

THX

```
$post_string = 'xml file'; // is ok <br/>
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://zp.toptrans.cz/api/xml/order/save/';
$header = array(
"POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n",
"Content-type: text/xml \r\n",
"Content-length: ".strlen($post_string)." \r\n",
"Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string );
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo "výstup dat: </br>";
echo "<pre>".$data."</pre>";
if(curl_errno($ch))
 print curl_error($ch);
else
 curl_close($ch);
die;
```

Comment: _code got error..._ What is the error message?

Comment: The `$header` array items should not contain `\r\n`

Comment: `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` only becomes useful when there are other options set and a stream is made available to log verbose information to

Answer (score 1):

To use the verbose output from curl you need to set some more options - as shown below. Also you should never set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false - make sure that you use a valid `cacert.pem` file and insist upon verifying SSL credentials of server

```
/*
    Download a copy of `cacert.pem` from
    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

    edit below path to appropriate location of
    saved cacert.pem file on your server.
*/
$cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';


$url='https://zp.toptrans.cz/api/xml/order/save/';
$payload='XML File';

$username='geronimo';
$password='balderdash';


/* create a stream for logging verbose info */
$vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

/* create an empty object for storing response and info */
$res = new stdclass;

/* initialise curl command */
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, sprintf( '%s:%s', $username, $password ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );

/* Add response and info to output object */
$res->response = curl_exec( $ch );
$res->info =(object)curl_getinfo( $ch );

/* Get the verbose information from the stream */
rewind( $vbh );
$res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
fclose( $vbh );

/* close connection */
curl_close( $ch );



if( $res ){
    if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){

        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $res->verbose, true ) );    #   seems OK
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $res->response, true ) );   #   incorrect username

    }
}
```

The above seems to work OK except for incorrect username and password details - and yields:

```
*   Trying 193.86.202.99...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to zp.toptrans.cz (193.86.202.99) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=CZ; L=Praha 10 - Michle; O=TOPTRANS EU, a.s., organiza\U010Dn� slo\U017Eka; CN=*.toptrans.cz
*  start date: Mar  6 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Jun  8 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "zp.toptrans.cz" matched cert's "*.toptrans.cz"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=Thawte TLS RSA CA G1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'geronimo'
> POST /api/xml/order/save/ HTTP/1.1
Host: zp.toptrans.cz
Authorization: Basic Z2Vyb25pbW86YmFsZGVyZGFzaA==
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 8 out of 8 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 13:55:44 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/7.1.7
< X-Powered-By: Nette Framework
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Vary: X-Requested-With,Accept-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: nette-browser=ce186cw9js; path=/; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=04933da0032891a2b005a70ee26badde; expires=Fri, 09-Aug-2019 13:55:44 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; path=/; HttpOnly
< Content-Length: 180
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
* Closing connection 0


  error


    Nesprávné uživatelské jméno.
```

Comment: Login is ok temporary login is here:
$user = 'spec460';
$pass = 'Spec1146';

Comment: Error message: - it means than is error on XML (post_string), but when I set to to false I get same error.

Comment: výstup dat: 
  error
  
  
    Není uveden povinný parametr: Firma vykládky (DISCHARGE_NAME)
    Není uveden povinný parametr: Obec vykládky (DISCHARGE_ADDRESS_CITY)
    Není uveden povinný parametr: Hmotnost (KG)
    Vykládka: Obec '' (PSČ ) nebyla nalezena! Vyplňte prosím adresu ručně.
    Nejsou zadány žádné kusy objednávky

Comment: I looks like curl not sending data (post_string). THX

Comment: I'd suggest trying using `http_build_query` on the POST data before sending which will create an  URL-encoded query string whereas sending "as-is" will likely be `multipart/form-data`